# Remove fill / color but keep border lines

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, fill

I would like to remove the colors (fill) of each province (shapefile), but keep the border lines, but can't seem to find out to remove fill? I am using QGIS 3.4.

[image]

Comment: Double-click a symbol, then set the filling to "no filling". Repeat for each category.

Comment: Click on the `Change...` button, remove the filling, then re-classify !

Comment: Thank you to both, the box to tick is "transparent filling" , not sure why I had missed that! Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only border lines, you don't need categorized symbology.

Open the Layer Properties and set Symbology to Single symbol. Click on Simple fill and select No Brush at Fill style.
[image]